# How to change the log level label with slf4j?

Tags: java, spring, label, logback, slf4j

I'm trying to change the label in the log.
I only want to get `{"level":"WARNING","msg":"test"}` instead of `{"level":"WARN","msg":"test"}`.

My class is:

```
package com.abc.def;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.warn("test");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

My logback.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <property resource="application.properties" />
   <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
         <providers>
            <logLevel>
               <fieldName>level</fieldName>
            </logLevel>
            <arguments>
               <includeNonStructuredArguments>false</includeNonStructuredArguments>
            </arguments>
            <stackTrace>
               <fieldName>stack</fieldName>
            </stackTrace>
            <message>
               <fieldName>msg</fieldName>
            </message>
         </providers>
      </encoder>
   </appender>
   <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
   </root>
</configuration>
```

I tried many changes but finally I don't any solution except creating a new class that extends net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder.

That seems a big stuff for a very small change.

---

Thanks Dhruv Pal.

I downloaded https://dlcdn.apache.org/logging/log4j/2.17.2/apache-log4j-2.17.2-bin.tar.gz and unzip it.

I launched

```
frederick@debian:~/Downloads/apache-log4j-2.17.2-bin$ java -cp log4j-core-2.17.2.jar 'org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$CustomLogger' MyLogger WARNING=300 > Logger.java
```

But:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/Strings
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Integers.parseInt(Integers.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Integers.parseInt(Integers.java:54)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$LevelInfo.<init>(Generate.java:1044)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$LevelInfo.parse(Generate.java:1051)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate.generate(Generate.java:1097)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate.generate(Generate.java:1063)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate.access$100(Generate.java:48)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$CustomLogger.main(Generate.java:1009)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Strings
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Go through `Generating Source Code for a Custom Logger Wrapper` [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html). It says it has code generators that can do your work  e.g ```java -cp log4j-core-2.17.2.jar org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.CustomLoggerGenerator \
        com.mycomp.MyLogger DEFCON1=350 DEFCON2=450 DEFCON3=550 > com/mycomp/MyLogger.java```.

Answer (score 0):

`logback.xml` is used for when you're using the [Logback library](https://logback.qos.ch/) you want to create a [log4j file](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/slf4j/slf4j-configuration-file-example/) with your relevant settings.

Comment: I don't understand how to do :(

Comment: @FrédérickSauvage have a look at the links in my comment. You essentially just need to replace your logback.xml with a log4j file, the settings are pretty similar in both files.